# Using Google ML Kit and Front Camera for PDF 417 bar code scanning on iOS

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

I am using Google ML Kit and iPad Air 4 for bar code scanning. For PDF417 bar code back camera works fine. I am not able scan  PDF417 using front camera. Is there any settings/code I need to do for front camera?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
  CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
  if (imageBuffer) {
    // Evaluate `self.currentDetector` once to ensure consistency throughout this method since it
    // can be concurrently modified from the main thread.
    Detector activeDetector = self.currentDetector;
    //[self resetManagedLifecycleDetectorsForActiveDetector:activeDetector];

       
    _lastFrame = sampleBuffer;
    MLKVisionImage *visionImage = [[MLKVisionImage alloc] initWithBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    UIImageOrientation orientation = [UIUtilities
        imageOrientationFromDevicePosition:_isUsingFrontCamera ? AVCaptureDevicePositionFront
                                                               : AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    visionImage.orientation = orientation;
    CGFloat imageWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    CGFloat imageHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    BOOL shouldEnableClassification = NO;
    BOOL shouldEnableMultipleObjects = NO;



    switch (activeDetector) {
      case DetectorOnDeviceBarcode: {
        MLKBarcodeScannerOptions *options = [[MLKBarcodeScannerOptions alloc] init];
        [self scanBarcodesOnDeviceInImage:visionImage
                                    width:imageWidth
                                   height:imageHeight
                                  options:options];
        break;
      }
      
    }
  } else {
    if (kTrace) NSLog(@"%@", @"Failed to get image buffer from sample buffer.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need some logic to handle the switch between the front and back cameras. You can check out ML Kit's vision quickstart sample app to see how that's handled (in particular, see all the logic dealing with `isUsingFrontCamera` in [this file](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExampleObjC/CameraViewController.m)).

Comment: I already have that. The MK kit is not scanning PDF417 code when using front camera

Comment: Please provide a sample photo that cannot be scanned.

Comment: I am trying to scan a a drivers license. It works with rear camera but not with front.

Comment: I just tried the barcode scanning in ML Kit's VisionExampleObjC quickstart sample app linked in my original answer above and I was able to scan the PDF417 code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417#/media/File:Wikipedia_PDF417.png) at the top of the PDF417 Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) using both the front and the back cameras. The scanned code is "Wikipedia".

Comment: Yes, that works but not with Physical Driver License. I also tried to use different resolution but still not success using front camera to 1080p or higher in - (void)setUpCaptureSessionOutput method.                                                                                                                    
      if (self->LaunchCameraForDriverLicense)
      {
          strongSelf.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
      }
      else
      {
          strongSelf.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
      }

Comment: Without a usable test image (of course, no image with user privacy should be shared) to verify and reproduce the issue, it's tough to continue this investigation.

Comment: You can generate the PDF 417 bar code using online tool (https://www.abarcode.net/online.aspx?barcode=PDF417)  and use ANSI format mentioned in link (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/77#issuecomment-196954858).

Comment: Have you tried a higher preset, e.g., `captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high`? It works for me after setting this to .high, back camera works easily with this, a bit challenging for the front camera, but can still detect at some frames.

Comment: According to the [Input image guidelines](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios#input-image-guidelines),  a PDF417 code need at least 1156 pixels wide, if the camera preset is mapped to AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 and used in portrait mode, the width will be at most 1080, which is lower than the minimum requirement of 1156.